# How to efficiently search on bulk data using jqgrid and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, jqgrid

I am having Jqgrid with  150 columns and millions of records for asp.net project.I am looking to add search functionality while giving each column data on search field. what method should I follow for efficient search.

Tried a method by inserting each record as a string to a table which is created to simply search while its created.Then searching can be done comparing search text with search table and displaying actual data from main table using sql Server.

But it is not working due to large number of columns.

Comment: why don't you load data on demand instead of loading all records at a time? And do search from database instead of searching on page using jquery?

Comment: Actually i am  doing searching on the database side.Just passing the searchtext from UI side.